# Is there a way to try/catch an entire page dynamically?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have a page on which mysterious JavaScript errors keep popping up. They appear to be coming from the application we use and do not own the source for. I'm working on a real solution to this issue, but we have a demo tomorrow and I was wondering if there is a way to just suppress JS errors page wide (like wrapping ALL the javascript components in a giant try catch).

Comment: What's a giant try catch going to do? It'll make your code fail silently, not work correctly.

Comment: @Matt well, if it works for the demo... See more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822397/suppress-done-but-with-errors-on-page-in-ie). A giant try/catch seems to be the tool of choice

Comment: @Pekka: eh, I _guess_... seems rather weak.

Comment: @Matt, `sed 's/seems rather/is totally/'`

Comment: I would not use one giant try-catch. It will make identifying and fixing *your* bugs (or even *their* bugs) so much harder. Consider using a wrapper around said API that *you* can control and wrap the individual actions (may be object-based or operation-based).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add a handler to the [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) event. In this case, all the errors that occur inside the window will be redirected to the handler of this event. (I did test this in Firefox and it worked, but I was having trouble with it in Chrome - my Chrome installation is pretty messed up, so that could be the problem, but there are Chromium bugs filed that relate to this issue: [bug #7771](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7771) and [bug #8939](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8939))

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    alert("Error on line " + line + " in " + url + ":\n" + msg);
    // return true to prevent browser from displaying error
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just saw the link that Pekka posted in the comment above... I didn't test this in IE (I don't have a Windows computer lying around), so I can't be sure that it works the way it should in that browser.

Comment: *Please, please, please don't use this though!* **FIX THE CODE.** I've wasted too much time dealing with this sort of awful idea in Microsoft SharePoint. (+1 for the answer though)

Comment: This is super! Thank you so much for this last minute fix. It should help out demo go great! 

P.S. Works in Firefox, chrome and IE8 (other ie versions untested)

Comment: Note that, although an onerror handler will catch exceptions, after a syntax or runtime JavaScript error it is possible that all event listeners are either deleted or disabled. The page can be seen, but no controls work. This effect happens regardless of whether a no onerror listener is set or not, but does NOT happen if a 'try' construct is used around the code containing the error instead of an onerror listener.