# Ignoring the Error object in try-catch in the correct way

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet:

```
try{
   client.close();
 }catch(e){}
```

where I try to catch an exception without using the Error object. Is there a more eloquent/better way in JavaScript? Maybe something like:

```
try{ client.close(); }
```

Comment: there's no other way that I know of. But I found this interesting answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847225/is-there-a-way-to-try-catch-an-entire-page-dynamically that suggests to add an handler to `window.onerror` event

Comment: You can do [`}catch{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_exception_identifier) which removes the error object like you're asking for, but I also don't believe there is a more eloquent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending of your needs, maybe useful something like this:

```
let ignoreException = (callback) => {
  try {
    callback();
  }
  catch(e)
  {   
  }
}
```

You can ignore exceptions in a single line of code:

```
ignoreException(() => tag.style.backgroundColor = "yellow");
ignoreException(() => tag.styleNotExists.backgroundColor = "yellow");
```

Check a sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/0cmdvo38/1/

Answer (score 0):

With [Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) documentation, you use `try ... finally`

```
try {
  writeMyFile(theData);
} finally {
  closeMyFile(); // whatever happened up there, always run this
}
```